# How do I return different values on different calls to a mock?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, powermockito

I have the following code which is getting the current counter value from DB. Then it updates the counter in DB and then again it retrieves the value.

```
int current = DBUtil.getCurrentCount();
DBUtil.updateCount(50);// it updates the current count by adding 50
int latest = DBUtil.getCurrentCount();
```

I want to mock the static methods in such a way that the first call should return 100 and the second call should return 150. How can I use PowerMockito to achieve this? I am using TestNG, Mockito along with PowerMock.

Comment: Why is `DBUtil` static? Inject an instance, then you don't need PowerMock.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Mockito supports changing the returned value; this support extends to PowerMockito. Just use [`OngoingStubbing.thenReturn(T value, T... values)`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html#thenReturn(T,%20T...))

> ```
> OngoingStubbing<T> thenReturn(T value, T... values)
> ```
>
> Sets consecutive return values to be returned when the method is called.
>   E.g:
>
> ```
> when(mock.someMethod()).thenReturn(1, 2, 3);
> ```
>
> Last return value in the sequence (in example: 3) determines the behavior of further consecutive calls.

So, in this case, you would do:

```
PowerMockito.when(DBUtil.getCurrentCount()).thenReturn(100, 150);
```

Note: this answer assumes you already know how to mock `static` methods. If you do not, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito).